# Como tirar uma seleção de um <input type="image">?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Eu estou programando pra web não faz muito tempo, e eu não consigo tirar uma seleção que fica quando eu clico?Alguém sabe como tirar?

[image: quando eu clico fica assim]

Comment: No CSS, `outline: none`.

Answer (score 2):

Isso é uma outline.
Aparece quando o elemento recebe :focus

Solução: CSS

```
textarea:focus, input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

Fonte: ["Fonte aqui"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397113/how-to-remove-border-outline-around-text-input-boxes-chrome)